# Replace specific string contains new line at end with new string in notepad++

Tags: text, replace, find, notepad++

In text file,

```
_MACRO_CALL
_MACRO_CALL (param)
```

I need to replace `_MACRO_CALL`(only First line) by `_MACRO_CALL;`

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `_MACRO_CALL\K$`
- Replace with: `;`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
_MACRO_CALL # literally
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]